# The event.target.value is not insert the userinput into a variable

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, forms

I have a html form and would like to use an eventlistener every click on submit button and insert the textarea and textinput to an alert.

the fuction of event.target.value is not working for me and the userinput is not set to a variable.

why eventa.target.value is not working? and how can I use the userinput?

Code:

```js
var myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');
var mytext = document.getElementById('mytext').target.value;
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');

myform.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  alert(mytext);
})

myform.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  alert(mytext);
})
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="myinput" />
  <br/>
  <textarea id="mytext" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: you are not using `target.value` in your provided javascript.

Comment: Nothing in code looks to use `event.target.value`. Also not clear what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish. Those alerts are pretty meaningless

Comment: However, you could try using `currentTarget` instead of `target`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn sorry, it was added. I am using Visual Studio Code and it marks the line on red or not giving auto complete.

Comment: Again...provide a proper explanation for what it is you want to accomplish as outlined in [ask]

Comment: *why eventa.target.value is not working?*  Because you are not using `Event.target.value`. You are trying to use `HTMLElement.target.value` which of course is `undefined`.

Comment: @charlietfl, I wrote it: I have a html form and would like to use an eventlistener every click on submit button and insert the textarea and textinput to an alert.

Comment: Then do things like `alert(mytext.value);`. The event object is not really needed for that task

Comment: `"message": "TypeError: document.getElementById(...).target is undefined",`. `HTMLElement`s do not have a `target` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below snippet and keep in mind that target of the event is what you put the click event on. so the target will be the submit button which you don't want. also `target.value` only works on the target not in any other element in the DOM

```js
    const myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');
    const mytext = document.getElementById('mytext');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(event){
       const textInput = myinput.value;
       const textArea = mytext.value;
       alert(`the text Input: '${textInput}' and the text Area: '${textArea}'`);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
input[type="text"] { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"] { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="" id="myform">
                <input type="text" id="myinput"/>
                <br/>
                <textarea id="mytext" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id='submit' />
              </form>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> why eventa.target.value is not working?

Because you are not using `Event.target.value`. You are trying to use `HTMLElement.target.value` which of course is `undefined` because `HTMLElement` does not have a `target` property. However, in the case of `HTMLInputElement` and `HTMLTextareaElement` they do have a `value` property which you can read in your event listener:

```js
var myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');
var mytext = document.getElementById('mytext');
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');

myform.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  console.log(mytext.value);
  console.log(myinput.value);
})

myform.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(mytext.value);
  console.log(myinput.value);
})
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="myinput" />
  <br/>
  <textarea id="mytext" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id='submit' />
</form>
```

Please note that the `change` event might only occur as soon as you the input element emits a `blur` event (depending on the browser you're using).